# Making a smart listeners notifier to avoid code duplication everywhere

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, arraylist

**ATTENTION:** The code is thread-safe, in other words, single-threaded. Only I can remove myself from the list of listeners.

I have 1000 different ArrayLists of listeners that I have to notify with code like below:

```
protected void onFlushed() {
    int size = listeners.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        listeners.get(i).onFlushed();
        int newSize = listeners.size();
        if (newSize == size - 1) {
            size--;
            i--;
        } else if (newSize != size) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException("List was altered while iterating! oldSize=" + size + " newSize=" + newSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a smart way to create a Notifier class that can take any ArrayList of listeners plus any listener method and perform the logic below for me OR I have to duplicate the code above everywhere for every listener method?

Am I asking too much from Java? :(

Comment: If your code is single-threaded, you should not need the mess of change detection here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current Java, there is no way to pass a method around, as you might do in a functional language, but you can create a `Function<Domain, Range>` interface and pass around objects implementing that interface.

You might consider using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), which supplies something resembling functional idioms and list-comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'm a little worried about the fact that most of this code seems to be dealing with concurrency issues in a not-very-safe way. Consider doing some locking around any code that accesses the same List of listeners. That way, you can simplify this code down to:

```
protected void onFlushed() {
    synchronized(listeners) {
        for (FlushListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onFlushed();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is not too bad to have repeated around your code. With that said, if there's some reason you need the logic that you have there, you could create a class something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;

public class Notifier<T> {
    public static interface NotificationRunnable<T> {
        public void notify(T t);
    }

    private ArrayList<T> listeners;
    public Notifier() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void addListener(T t) {
        listeners.add(t);
    }

    public void notifyAll(NotificationRunnable<T> nr) {
        int size = listeners.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            nr.notify(listeners.get(i));
            int newSize = listeners.size();
            if (newSize == size - 1) {
                size--;
                i--;
            } else if (newSize != size) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException("List was altered while iterating! oldSize=" + size + " newSize=" + newSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then the code to call it would look like:

```
Notifier<FlushListener> notifier = new Notifier();
notifier.addListener(new FlushListener());

public void onFlushed() {
    notifier.notifyAll(new NotificationRunnable<FlushListener>(){
        public void notify(FlushListener t) {
            t.onFlushed();
        }
    });
}
```

Or even get it down to one line in the actual method:

```
NotificationRunnable<FlushListener> flushRunnable = new NotificationRunnable<FlushListener>(){
    public void notify(FlushListener t) {
        t.onFlushed();
    }
}

public void onFlushed() {
    notifier.notifyAll(flushRunnable);
}
```

Comment: OMG, there is too much object creation everywhere. Not your fault, but still. The code is single-threaded, in other words, thread-safe. The only "concurrent" modification here is I removing myself from the list of listeners.

Comment: Listeners themselves shouldn't really be deciding what they listen to, so there probably shouldn't be any listeners removing themselves from the list. If you want to loop over a collection and remove some of them, you could use an Iterator and call the .remove() method (if the Collection supports it) to avoid ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

Comment: @JoeK The situation is: something blows, and exception is thrown and my listener is returned to the pool and it is removed from the list of listeners. Does it sound weird/wrong ?

Comment: So then what I would do is have the listener's method throw an exception, which is then caught by the code that loops over all listeners and removes the listener (by using Iterator's .remove() method, as mentioned above)